# NIntegrate returns MemoryAllocationFailure

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to compute the following integral numerically:

$$
\int_0^\infty 
\int_0^\infty 
\int_0^\infty 
{8 \left(\frac{z^2 \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u+v+z)^2}-1\right)}{(u+v+z)^2}+\frac{z^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u+v+z)^2} \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} u (u+2 (v+z))}-1\right)}{u (u+2 (v+z))}+\frac{(v+z)^2 \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u+v+z)^2}-e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\right)}{(u+v) (u+v+2 z)}-\frac{(v+z)^2 \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u+v+z)^2}-1\right)}{(u+v+z)^2}\right)} \times\frac{1}{v z^2 (v+z)^2 (v+2 z)}
\, \mathrm du
\, \mathrm dv 
\, \mathrm dz
$$
The code is like this

```
I = (8 (((-1 + E^(-(1/2) (u + v + z)^2)) z^2)/(u + v + 
z)^2 - ((-1 + E^(-(1/2) (u + v + z)^2)) (v + z)^2)/(u + v + 
z)^2 + ((-E^(-(z^2/2)) + E^(-(1/2) (u + v + z)^2)) (v + 
z)^2)/((u + v) (u + v + 2 z)) + (
E^(-(1/2) (u + v + z)^2) (-1 + E^(1/2 u (u + 2 (v + z)))) z^2)/(
u (u + 2 (v + z)))))/(v z^2 (v + z)^2 (v + 2 z))

NIntegrate[I, {z, 0, Infinity}, {u, 0, Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

When I put PrecisionGoal to 3, this actually works. But when I change it to 4, it gives MemoryAllocationFailure. Is there any work around they I can try?

Comment: `NIntegrate[Simplify[Together[i]], {z,0, Infinity}, {u,0,Infinity}, {v,0,Infinity}, PrecisionGoal->4]` works just fine. Note I used `i` instead of `I` which is defined to be `Sqrt[-1]`, sometimes you can get away with things like that and sometimes it will bite you. Changing the `4` to `5` again fails probably because of all the denominators which can have values of zero